# How to set button focus in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, tvos

!!! `TVOS` !!!

I have list of buttons and it somehow autofocus first button in that list (when view is loaded). Is there any way how to focus another button in that list using `SwiftUI`?

I know there is `preferredFocusedView` in `UIKit` but id like to do this in `SwiftUI`.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I would also like to know this. I have navigation bar with first button stealing focus by default. I would like to switch focus to a ``Button`` below.

Answer (score -1):

**SwiftUI 2.0**

*Note: !! Partial solution !!*

The following approach, as tested with Xcode 12b5 / tvOS 14 works **only with stacks** and does not work (in any tested combination) for List/ScrollView.

Anyway for small on-screen sets of buttons it is applicable so worth posting.

[image]

```
struct DemoPreferredFocusView: View {
    @Namespace var ns
    @Environment(\.resetFocus) var resetFocus
    @AppStorage("initialButton") var initialButton: Int = 3

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { i in
                Button(action: {
                    print(">> tapped \(i)")
                    self.initialButton = i
                }) {
                    Text("Button \(i)")
                }
                .prefersDefaultFocus(i == initialButton, in: ns)
            }.focusScope(ns)
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.resetFocus.callAsFunction(in: ns)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution with scrollView ? I'm trying to fix this issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63828559/how-to-navigate-between-multiple-horizontal-list-with-swiftui-on-tvos) by adding focusable view that reset focus