# Focus on the specific item in the List on SwiftUI (tvOS)

Tags: swiftui, tvos

I am having a hard time trying to figured out how to focus on a specific cell/row in the list in the SwiftUI 2.0 and tvOS 14. I need to be able to focus and select a specific record when I am navigated to a view. However when the focus is switched to the list, some random row is focused. I've tried ScrollView and List to create a list of items with Buttons as items and with appropriate prefersDefaultFocus. Nothing works. Here's some sample code:

```
struct ChannelListView: View {
    @Namespace private var namespace
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : LiveViewModel
    @State var selection = Set<ChannelItem>()
    var body: some View {
        List(viewModel.channels, selection: $selection){ item in
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                        Button(action: {
                        }){
                            ChannelItemView(item: item, selectedItem: $viewModel.selectedChannel, onSelected: { id in
                            })
                            .padding(.vertical, 2)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(ChannelButtonStyle())
                        .prefersDefaultFocus(item == viewModel.selectedChannel, in: namespace)
            }
        }
        .focusScope(namespace)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63550463/12299030

Comment: Yeah... I have a big scrollable list. This solution doesn't seem to be working with list/scrollview